# Accessing jquery objects with selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have an unordered list with several divs contained inside. Each list item is created with jquery and put into a variable.

I need a way to select the :nth-child(even) of each div within the jquery object.

```
ele = myList.append("<li> \
<div class='name'>"+this.name+"</div> \
<div class='test'>test</div> \
</li>");
```

How would I use the variable "ele" within a jquery object to get the nth-child contained within?

What I had imagined, which doesn't work:

```
$(ele+" div:nth-child(even)").addClass("my-class");
```

Another thing I imagined

```
ele.children("div:nth-child(even)").addClass('my-class'));
```

Also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
ele.find("div:nth-child(even)").addClass('my-class');
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2grAN/)